# Input field losing focus in nested AngularJS repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having some weird behavior with a nested angular list. The focus is immediately lost after the first letter I type.

The outer repeat is a list of attributes, identified by the attribute name (not index). The inner repeat is a subarray of an attribute, identified by index.

The display and binding work as expected but when I change something, e.g. insert a letter, the focus is lost and I can't type another letter or anything. I have to click the field again.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in configuration.metaData">

    <label>{{key}}</label>

    <input data-ng-repeat="subKey in configuration[key]"
           data-ng-model="configuration[key][$index]"
           type="text"
           name="{{subKey}}">
</div>
```

Some additional information that might be helpful:

- this snippet is included in a form via ng-include
- I get the same behavior with textarea
- metaData contains data about the attributes of the object (also datatype etc.) but the real values are in the configuration itself

Comment: a jsFiddle would be nice. I think you can avoid the problem by using 'track by $index' in all your ng-repeats.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I was working on a fiddle and noticed the same thing. Thanks! :)

Comment: btw if you add this as an answer I could accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be avoided by using 'track by $index' in all your ng-repeats.

The reason is that if the content changes, angularjs will still know that 
it's the same object, because angular track the items (key, value) by their position in the array.

When (key, value) changes, without track by $index, as the "value" changes, it's considered as a new object, which introduce the loose of focus (the element is destroyed then recreated by angularjs).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input data-ng-repeat="subKey in configuration[key]"
       data-ng-model="configuration[key][$index]"
```

This is very strange and probably wrong. I.e. by typing smth you change configuration[key][0] and thus first subKey...

I guess you meant something like this:

```
<input data-ng-repeat="subKey in configuration[key]"
       data-ng-model="subKey.value"
       type="text"
       name="{{subKey.name}}">
```

with model

```
  $scope.configuration = {
    metaData : {
      test : 'test'
    },
    test : [{ name : 'a', value : 'aa'}, { name : 'b', value : 'bb'}]
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IwDS3141BWcv9t5BcAka?p=preview

Comment: You are right. I'm changing the model im working on and not the value. I get an indexed json array, thus the strange behavior. track by $index solves this. I can't change the data model in this case.